# Why a non-root installation can work across the whole cluster?

Tags: python, cluster, root, hpc, anaconda

I recently installed anaconda (which includes a new python3) locally in my account folder on a cluster with a dozen of nodes (each node with several cores). I use it to install some package P that is used in my python programs.
--- In short, I probably can say I just non-root installed a python locally.

I originally presumed that I can python3 run programs with P only on the node where I installed them, which is presumably the portal node of the cluster. However, I notice that I can actually even submit jobs of such programs running on any nodes on the cluster. I also made sure that I indeed use the newly installed python3.x from anaconda, not the python2.x already there long before.
This happens on two different clusters (one with PBS job system, the other with LSF Lava).

So why is this possible?